# Sbt Plugins vs Compiler Plugins

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to understand why Adding sbt plugins in plugins.sbt in the project, works perfectly fine, but if I add the compiler plugins in that file it does not work ?

I thought any .sbt or .scala file in project, is made available for the build definition.

The only place where compiler plugins works is in the build.sbt. Hence i am confused as to why ?

In particular i am working with Kind-Projector

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.typelevel" %% "kind-projector" % "0.11.3" cross CrossVersion.full)
```

I see the following alias for the function

```
/** Adds `dependency` to `libraryDependencies` in the auto-compiler plugin configuration. */
def addCompilerPlugin(dependency: ModuleID): Setting[Seq[ModuleID]] =
libraryDependencies += compilerPlugin(dependency)
```

Hence just trying to understanding, what makes it that it can only be added to the build.sbt and not plugins.sbt in project/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remeber **sbt** is recursive.

`.sbt` define things that are available in the current layer.
`.scala` files define thins that will be available in the next layer.

Adding an **sbt** plugin in `project/bar.sbt` is adding that plugin to the meta layer, as such the meta-layer that compiles the **sbt** you are using to compile your project adds those plugins to the next **sbt** layer.

So if you add a compiler plugin in `project/foo.sbt` then you are adding that compiler plugin to the compiler used to compile the project *(meta)* layer of **sbt**, but it will not be available in the current layer of **sbt**. That is the reason why compiler plugins are added in the `build.sbt` file, so they are added to the compiler used to compile your code.